# Calculating the length of a string using fphp

Tags: php

I am using `fphp` to create a pdf using data retrieved from an `SQL` database. Is works fine but I want to only display information where there is data in the database. For example I only want the following line to be executed if the length of $obsComment is greater than 0.

```
$pdf->MultiCell(0, 5, $obsComment,0, "J");
```

How do I calculate the length of a string using `fphp`? I have tried:

```
If (GetStringWidth(string $obsComment)>0)
{
$pdf->MultiCell(0, 5, $obsComment,0, "J");
}
```

but this does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: if (strlen((string)$obsComment) > 0)

Comment: Perfect - thank you. If you add as an answer I will accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Test for the length of the string:

```
if (strlen((string)$obsComment) > 0)
```